# Opposite of 'Ancestor' in OOP

Tags: oop, inheritance, phrases

I am looking for the best term to use to describe a child that inherits an ancestor.

For example, a 'Car' object may derive from its ancestor 'Vehicle'. However, is there a better/more suitable word to use than *derivative* for the inverse?

Comment: I think the common term is "descendent", although "parent"/"child" is also quite common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent and child

So a car derives from it's parent vehicle; and a vehicle has multiple children such as car, boat and plane.

Comment: Thanks, guess I was overthinking it :)

Answer (score 8):

Ancestor/Descendant are a more common pairing when there can be intermediate layers between the items under discussion.

E.g. if we have `Vehicle` -> `Wheeled Vehicle` -> `Car` (and assuming other possible classes also exist), both `Vehicle` and `Wheeled Vehicle` are ancestors of `Car` and both `Wheeled Vehicle` and `Car` are descendants of `Vehicle`. We would describe `Vehicle` as *the* parent of `Wheeled Vehicle` and `Car` as *a* child of `Wheeled Vehicle` but we wouldn't generally use parent or child to describe the relationship between `Vehicle` and `Car`.

Answer (score 2):

"Inherited class" and "derived class" work well. At times instances of objects have parent/child relationships that have nothing to do with inheritance, like parent nodes and child nodes. In those cases referring to "parent" and "child" classes in the same context could be confusing.

Also, using the parent/child metaphor, every child is a parent, not every parent is a child, and some classes are infertile (sealed.)